# Count Distinct values in one column based on other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
app_id  supplier_reached    creation_date   platform
10001       1            9/11/2018         iOS
10001       2            9/18/2018         iOS
10002       1            5/16/2018       android
10003       1            5/6/2018        android
10004       1            10/1/2018       android
10004       1            2/3/2018        android
10004       2            2/2/2018           web
10005       4            1/5/2018           web
10005       2            5/1/2018        android
10006       3            10/1/2018         iOS
10005       4            1/1/2018          iOS
```

The objective is to find the unique number of app_id submitted per month.

If I just do a `count(distinct app_id)` I will get the following results:

```
Group by month  count(app number)
     Jan              1
     Feb              1
     may              3
  september           1
   october            2
```

However, an application is considered unique based on a combination of other fields as well. For example, for the month of January, `the app_id` is the same however a combination of `app_id`, `supplier_reached` and `platform` show different values and hence the `app_id` should be counted twice.
Following the same pattern, the desired result should be:

```
Group by month  Desired answer
     Jan              2
     Feb              2
     may              3
   september          2
    october           2
```

Lastly, there can be many other columns in the table which may or may not contribute to the uniqueness of an application.

Is there a way to do this type of count in SQL?

I am using Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, in Redshift `count(distinct ...)` does not work with multiple fields.

You can first group by the columns that you want to be unique and then count the records like this:

```
select month,count(1) as app_number 
from (
    select month,app_id,supplier_reached,platform
    from your_table
    group by 1,2,3,4
)
group by 1
```

Comment: `there can be many other columns in the table which may .... contribute to the uniqueness` just add/change the columns used in the inner subquery to suit your purpose. Note the answer by Erwin Brandstetter also, (there are good reasons to avoid concatenations).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Postgres or Redshift supports `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with multiple arguments.  One workaround is to use concatenation:

```
count(distinct app_id || ':' || supplier_reached || ':' || platform)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objective's mean is wrong.

You don't want

`to find the unique number of app_id submitted per month`

you want

`to find the unique number of app_id + supplier_reached + platform submitted per month`.

And so, you need to use a) combination of columns like `count(distinct col1||col2||col3)` or b)

```
select t1.month, count(t1.*)
  (select distinct 
         app_id, 
         supplier_reached,  
         platform, 
         month 
   from sometable) t1
group by month
```

Comment: I tried doing this but removing the `distinct` led to double counting of apps because in certain cases the records are duplicates as well. :|

Comment: And no, I dont want `to find the unique of app_id + supplier_reached + platform`.

The definition given by the stakeholders states that an application's uniqueness is characterized by multiple fields even though the app_id might be the same(due to the DB design).
I am just trying to count as per the definition provided.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can count distinct [`ROW` values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) conveniently in Postgres:

```
SELECT month, count(DISTINCT (app_id, supplier_reached, platform)) AS dist_apps
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The `ROW` keyword would be just noise here:

```
count(DISTINCT ROW(app_id, supplier_reached, platform))
```

I would discourage concatenating columns for the purpose. This is comparatively expensive, error prone (think of distinct data types and locale-dependent `text` representation) and introduces corner-case errors if the used separator can be contained in column values.

Alas, [not supported by Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html):

> ```
> ...
> Value expressions
>     Subscripted expressions  
>     Array constructors  
>     Row constructors
> ...
> ```